# How to use serializer in Django REST Framework

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm really new at Django REST framework. It's a very noob question but I'm not able to understand how does a serializer work? How do we send data to the serializer and how do we get data from it.
I'm trying to serialize my queryset as a list of dictionaries.
Here is my **`views.py`**:

```
def get(self,request):
    z= int(request.GET.get('q',''))
    queryset=[]
    queryset.append(models.Cart.objects.filter(UserId=z).values('id'))
    k=[]
    for values in queryset:
        k.append(models.ProductsDiscription.objects.filter(id=values).values())
    abc = serializers.NewSerializer(k,many=True)
    return JsonResponse({'pcartlist':((abc))})
```

If I don't use a serializer I get an error:

```
k:queryset is not json serializable.
```

So I tried to create a serializer, however I'm still getting the same error. I don't have any idea how to work with serializer.

**`serializers.py`**

```
class NewSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    product_id= serializers.IntegerField()
```

k is the list of dictionries and i also dont know which field to use for that.

I have tried reading and understanding from every possible place but I'm unable to understand how serializers work. Please help me, if possible by giving a very simple example. It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pass a queryset directly to a serializer. If you want to serialize a model, you can use a `modelSerializer`. A model serializer also needs a model name as a `META` attribute. The documentation can be found [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#inspecting-a-modelserializer)

To serialize a queryset:

```
qs = YourModel.objects.all()
serializer = YourSerializer(qs, many=True)
```

The result after serialization can be obtained from `serializer.data`. You can do `print (serializer.data)` to see the result.

Comment: i know about `Modelserializer` .i just want to know to how will i send data to serializer and will get back the serialized data.As it is a get request i have to return data not save it.

Comment: Edited the response to reflect your additional questions.

Comment: If you want to store a dictionary, convert the dictionary into a string using the python `json` library. You can do `string_dict = json.dumps(dict)`. Later when you want to use the dict, you can do `dict = json.loads(string_dict)`. You can then use `serializers.TextField` for this.